# How to avoid mips64el using CMake when cross compiling for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake

I am trying to compile a C++ library to use it with an Android app. I am using CMake to generate the makefile, but when I configure the CMake script, the configuration takes "mips64el" as compilation reference (CMAKE_AR, CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER, CMAKE_C_COMPILER, etc.). This compiler is not compatible with the flags generated in the makefile, so the building process fails.

The most strange thing is that in a second PC, the same configuration defines "arm-linux" as compilation reference.

As additional note, I am using Ubuntu 14.04 in both pc's. I am defining "armeabi-v7a" as Android ABI, and Android API level as 9. Also, I have included the path to the NDK libraries (android-ndk-r10c) in the environment variables (as ANDROID_NDK and in the PATH variable).

Any sugestion?

Comment: You can set `arch` and `CMAKE_x_COMPILER_TARGET`.

Comment: I tryed to define CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_TARGET = arm-linux-androideabi, similar to what is explained in "https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html", but nothing changed.

Comment: What ndk do you have in the computer that works? I recommend you to download the last one to avoid this configurations, some times with 64bits fails. I will use: android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86_64.bin . API 9 is very old, if fails with that NDK revision, try to put API 14.

Comment: I have tested with that exact version and I tryed with the api 21 too. I downloaded the 'android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86_64.bin' just yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

The error was in the toolchain itself. It looks like the libraries in the first computer were ignored in the configuration step because those library versions where not listed in the toolchain, so the only available configurations was the mips64el.

I have updated the toolchain file from [this](https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake) github repository, and it is working properly now.